# How to get vocals like that? [chopped/pitched/reverb]

Tags: vocals, reverb

https://soundcloud.com/orlogin/dead-sea

In 0:37 - u can hear vocals.
How they were edited so that they sound so deep and excellent?

They are chopped into melody, dipped in reverb effect, fades added, delays, pitched up/down and ....what else? I can't get result like this...

Here is tutorial with similar effect on vocal but it's not exactly that :(

Anybody had experience with vocals like that?

I'll be very grateful.
Regards

Comment: Is it possible to hear your attempt at replicating this? - To be able to distinguish what it's missing. Correct me if I'm wrong but I don't hear any bass in the vocals, only in the background synth

Answer (score 1):

The various effects are quite simple:

There is pitch shifting, some delay, a fair amount of reverb, and a bit of fade and panning, and the vox are cut in and out - but the most important thing is the filtering.

A lot of the vocals are run through a low pass filter, chopping out a lot of the treble.

As cworner commented, we'd need to hear your attempts and understand what you are trying. As it stands, there will just be a lot of trial and error.

- First, you want to manage your samples so they happen at the times you need them.
- Then sort out your panning and the cut in and out for each sample
- Apply your low pass filters to each sample and decide on frequency and slope
- Sort out delay and reverb
- Iterate over and over again